# Photo RSS Feed Display

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

i have a wordpress blog http://cgvector.com and I want to **show Featured Images in RSS Feed**. How can i do this? My feed address is: http://feeds.feedburner.com/cgvector

i have add this code but it's not working.

```
function featuredtoRSS($content) {
    global $post;

    if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ){
    $content = '' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'thumbnail', array( 'style' => 'float:left; margin:0 15px 15px 0;' ) ) . '' . $content;
    }

    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'featuredtoRSS');
add_filter('the_content_feed', 'featuredtoRSS');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function custom_feed($content) {
    return wp_get_attachment_image(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full') . '<br />' . $content;
}
add_filter('the_content_feed', 'custom_feed');
```

This one should do the trick for you...

Comment: where should i paste this code in function file in start in end under php code or without php code..

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine, but you can paste this code (all most same, anyways) in your`functions.php`that is located inside your `wp-content/themes/yourtheamefolder`

```
function img_to_rss($content) {
    global $post;
    if(has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {
        $content = '<p>'.get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID).'</p>' . get_the_content();
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'img_to_rss');
add_filter('the_content_feed', 'img_to_rss');
```

Keep on mind that `Feedburner` caches your feed, so wait 12-24 hours for it to update before you see these changes.

Comment: it not working i have add complete code in jsfiddle please check
http://jsfiddle.net/rizwanabbasi/ZXPXB/

Comment: I think alternatively you can try one of these plugins [WP RSS Images](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-rss-images/screenshots/) and [Insert RSS Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-insert-rss-thumbnails/), hope this helps.

Comment: wp Rss Images i have used before this is not good but other i am going to check hope this will work thanks for your reply

Comment: please check my feed it's not looking good i want to embed img in page it's just show image link http://feeds.feedburner.com/cgvector

Comment: Check out [this](http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/feedburner-feed-not-displaying-photo-with-each-new-entry).